# Read metadata in grpc on the server side c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, metadata, grpc, proto

I am sending token in metadata from the client side

```
      Channel channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
  ItemQuery item = new ItemQuery() { Id = "abc" };
  var client = new MyService.MyServiceClient(channel);
  Metadata data = new Metadata
  {
    { "token", "Bearer xhrttt" }
  };
  var reply = client.GetItem(item, data);
```

But not able to find a way to fetch it in server side, Any help is appreciated

below is an example of how my server-side code looks(i tried certain other ways also)

```
public override Task<ItemResponse> GetItem(ItemQuery request , ServerCallContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var a = context.RequestHeaders["token"]; // not working 
            ItemResponse itmRes = new ItemResponse();
            if (request.Id == "foo")
            {
                itmRes.Items.Add(new Item() { Id = "foo", Name = "foobar" });
            }
            return Task.FromResult(itmRes);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How are you even calling `var reply = client.GetItem(item, data);`? That should be giving you a build error `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Grpc.Core.Metadata' to 'Grpc.Core.ServerCallContext' (CS1503)`

Comment: no, it doesn't give me the error.

Comment: You're right. I'm an idiot. I was using the server object instead of the client object.

Comment: @Nick never mind, did the solution helped you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the code to fetch metadata in c#

```
                Metadata.Entry metadataEntry = context.RequestHeaders.FirstOrDefault(m =>
            String.Equals(m.Key, "token", StringComparison.Ordinal));

            if (metadataEntry.Equals(default(Metadata.Entry)) || metadataEntry.Value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Token value is {0}", metadataEntry.Value);
```

for more details refer https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Grpc.Core/ServerCallContext/-/php-servercallcontext-class-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-grpc-headers) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-grpc-trailers), getting and setting metadata can be summarized:

`GreeterService.cs` (GrpcGreeter.csproj)

```cs
public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    context.WriteResponseHeadersAsync(
        new Metadata() { { "server_header", "nice to see you too" } });

    context.ResponseTrailers.Add(
        new Metadata.Entry("server_trailer", "see you later") { });

    string? client_header = context.RequestHeaders.GetValue("client_header");
    return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
    {
        Message = $"i got your header, {request.Name}. it reads: {client_header}"
    });
}
```

`Program.cs` (GrpcGreeterClient.csproj)

```cs
// The port number must match the port of the gRPC server.
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7143");

Greeter.GreeterClient client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
var call = client.SayHelloAsync(
                new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" },
                new Metadata() { { "client_header", "hey there" } });

Metadata headers = await call.ResponseHeadersAsync;
Console.WriteLine($"Server Header: {headers.GetValue("server_header")}");

HelloReply rsp = await call.ResponseAsync;
Console.WriteLine($"Server Response: {rsp.Message}");

Metadata trailers = call.GetTrailers();
string? myTrailer = trailers.GetValue("server_trailer");
Console.WriteLine($"Server Trailers: {myTrailer}");
```

Output:

```
Server Header: nice to see you too
Server Response: i got your header, GreeterClient. it reads: hey there
Server Trailers: see you later
```